# Hanging loop with sleep()

Tags: c, process, signals, sleep

I'm trying to learn how to handle signals. In my program I have an array of pids of earlier created subprocesess. No I want to every couple seconds send a sigtstp signal to one of them. He just have to send sigchld to parent process and exit. Parent process should print an exit code of exited process and create next one in the place of exit one. Everything works fine in first loop but it hangs in second. So on output  get:

```
loop
slept
forking
in to array
loop
Zakonczyl sie potomek 3934 z kodem 0.
```

So it's seems that sleep works in first loop but not in second. Or just main process didn't get back control after handling signal but this should't happen. So I have no idea whats may be wrong here.

```
while(1) {
                printf("loop\n");
                sleep(5);
                printf("slept\n");
                int r = rand() % n;
                if(kill(process_tab[r],SIGTSTP) < 0) {
                        printf("Error while sending sigtstp signal.\n");
                } else {
                        printf("forking\n");
                        if((child = fork()) < 0) {
                                printf("Fork failed.\n");
                        } else if(child == 0) {//to sie dzieje w procesie
                                if(signal(SIGTSTP,&catch_sigtstp)) {
                                        printf("Error while setting signal handler.\n");
                                        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                                }
                                while(1) {
                                }
                        } else { //to sie dzieje w parencie
                                process_tab[r] = child;
                                printf("in to array\n");
                        }
                }
}
```

And here are handlers.

```
void catch_sigtstp(int signal) {
        kill(ppid,SIGCHLD);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void catch_sigchld (int signal) {
        int status;
        pid_t child = wait(&status);
        printf("Zakonczyl sie potomek %d z kodem %d.\n",child,status);
}
```

Comment: You never update `i` or `n` when you fork new children. The child shouldn't send `SIGCHLD`, this is sent automatically by the OS whenever a child exits.

Comment: Copied wrong line there. Should by process_tab[r] and how it is in my code. n is number of procesess so it remains the same couse i'm not changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `fflush` after `printf`.

```
printf("Something\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Otherwise you may not get the output as `stdio` is buffered by default.

Edit: Issues of handler

It is pretty unsafe to use `printf` function in signal handler, as it is not reentrant. Also, the `catch_sigchild` function can be modified:

```
void catch_sigchld (int signal) {
    int status;
    pid_t child;

    while ((child = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
       // may be something else?
       // ...printf("Zakonczyl sie potomek %d z kodem %d.\n",child,status); 
    }
}
```

The reason is that one signal can be delivered for multiple dead children.

Edit: blocking signal when printing.

To avoid deadlock inside stdio, you should block the signal:

```
sigset_t set;

sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGCHILD);

...
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
printf("my output");
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
...
```

Edit: as @Barmar has pointed, you parent process will receive SIGCHILD signal twice: once from your child'd signal handler, and one from OS.

To fix, it might be sufficient to remove your own signal source:

```
void catch_sigtstp(int signal) {
    // kill(ppid,SIGCHLD); //< This one causes two signals per one child
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: I have added fflush after every printf and it doesn't change anything. Output is still the same.

Comment: `stdout` is line-buffered by default, so it shouldn't be necessary if he ends every printf with `\n`.

Comment: Since he only kills one child every 5 seconds, and they don't die on their own, multiple SIGCHLD signals shouldn't happen in this program. It's a good idea to write SIGCHLD handler that way, but it can't be causing this problem.

Comment: @Barmar He is likely deadlocking. So it is either on `printf` or on `wait`. potential `wait` deadlock can be avoided, and for `printf` he needs to block the signal while printing...

Comment: I think it's because he's sending his own SIGCHLD. He sends SIGCHLD, the handler calls `wait()`, the process exits and `wait()` returns. Then the OS sends SIGCHLD, so he goes into the handler again, but now there's no exiting process for `wait()` to report on, so it hangs. So your fixed handler should actually solve it.

Comment: Removing `kill(ppid,SIGCHLD);` helped.